# iPython from WinPython raise ImportError for PyGObject/PyGi

Tags: python, ipython, importerror, pygobject

Once again I have to program scientific software. But this time it has to run on a measuring computer with Windows. For this purpose I've installed [WinPython 3.3.5 (32 bit)](http://winpython.sourceforge.net/) and [PyGObject 3.12.2 with GTK+3.8.9 (32 bit)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/files/?source=navbar).

WinPython Interpreter works:

```
Python 3.3.5 (v3.3.5:62cf4e77f785, Mar  9 2014, 10:37:12) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (In
tel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys; print(sys.path)
['',
'C:\\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\\python-3.3.5\\python33.zip',
'C:\\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\\python-3.3.5\\DLLs',
'C:\\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\\python-3.3.5\\lib',
'C:\\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\\python-3.3.5',
'C:\\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\\python-3.3.5\\lib\\site-packages',
'C:\\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\\python-3.3.5\\lib\\site-packages\\FontTools',
'C:\\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\\python-3.3.5\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
'C:\\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\\python-3.3.5\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
'C:\\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\\python-3.3.5\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
>>> import gi
>>>
```

WinPython Command Prompt works too:

```
C:\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\python-3.3.5>echo %path%
C:\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\python-3.3.5\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4;
C:\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\python-3.3.5\;
C:\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\python-3.3.5\DLLs;
C:\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\python-3.3.5\Scripts;
C:\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\python-3.3.5\..\tools;
C:\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\python-3.3.5\..\tools\gnuwin32\bin;
C:\MinGW\bin;
C:\Windows\system32;
C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\python-3.3.5\..\tools\TortoiseHg

C:\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\python-3.3.5>python
Python 3.3.5 (v3.3.5:62cf4e77f785, Mar  9 2014, 10:37:12) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (In
tel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gi
>>>
```

Although the WinPython is portable, the normal Windows' cmd.exe works too:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

C:\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\python-3.3.5>echo %path%
C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\
System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\

C:\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\python-3.3.5>python
Python 3.3.5 (v3.3.5:62cf4e77f785, Mar  9 2014, 10:37:12) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (In
tel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys; print(sys.path)
['',
'C:\\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\\python-3.3.5\\python33.zip',
'C:\\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\\python-3.3.5\\DLLs',
'C:\\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\\python-3.3.5\\lib',
'C:\\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\\python-3.3.5',
'C:\\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\\python-3.3.5\\lib\\site-packages',
'C:\\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\\python-3.3.5\\lib\\site-packages\\FontTools',
'C:\\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\\python-3.3.5\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
'C:\\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\\python-3.3.5\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
'C:\\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\\python-3.3.5\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
>>> import gi
>>>
```

But IPython Qt Console doesn't:

```
Python 3.3.5 (v3.3.5:62cf4e77f785, Mar  9 2014, 10:37:12) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 2.0.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
%guiref   -> A brief reference about the graphical user interface.

In [1]: import sys; print(sys.path)
['',
'C:\\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\\python-3.3.5\\python33.zip',
'C:\\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\\python-3.3.5\\DLLs',
'C:\\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\\python-3.3.5\\lib',
'C:\\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\\python-3.3.5',
'C:\\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\\python-3.3.5\\lib\\site-packages',
'C:\\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\\python-3.3.5\\lib\\site-packages\\FontTools',
'C:\\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\\python-3.3.5\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
'C:\\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\\python-3.3.5\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
'C:\\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\\python-3.3.5\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
'C:\\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\\python-3.3.5\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions',
'C:\\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\\settings\\.ipython']

In [2]: import gi
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-a23efdcdbcd8> in <module>()
----> 1 import gi

C:\WinPython-32bit-3.3.5.0\python-3.3.5\lib\site-packages\gi\__init__.py in <module>()
     34                       'of "import gobject" to "from gi.repository import GObject".')
     35 
---> 36 from ._gi import _gobject
     37 from ._gi import _API
     38 from ._gi import Repository

ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.


In [3]:
```

On the one hand iPython is very useful and on the other hand py2exe also doesn't find gi module on every console with similar message.

**EDIT:** `import gi` works in IPython from WinPython 3.3.2.3 (32 bit). No more time to try from which version it no longer works. Next step is to get GTK+3 working with cx_Freeze.